# Magento module with two front page

Tags: magento

I have created one Magento module. It's working perfectly. But my problem is i want to create a module with more than one front page like:

```
Page 1:
www.magento.com/part/

Page 2:
www.magento.com/part/view/
```

In my part page there is one form and when i submit this it redirect to view page and i want to display some data whatever pass from part page.

Following is my directory structure:

```
app\code\local\HK\Part\Block
app\code\local\HK\Part\controllers
app\code\local\HK\Part\etc
app\code\local\HK\Part\Helper
app\code\local\HK\Part\Model
app\code\local\HK\Part\sql

app\design\frontend\default\default\layout
app\design\frontend\default\default\template

app\etc\modules
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup your router correctly you just have to add another action in your controller. In your case it should be `viewAction` in `PartController.php`

Comment: Thanks Buzz for your reply. I have added viewAction in my PartController.php. But not getting where i have to add router?

Comment: @Hardik What are the files available in your `controllers` folder?

I am guessing it should already have IndexController.php

Answer (score 0):

A basic Magento URL structure can be broken down as follows:

`<base url>/<module front-name>/<controller>/<action>/<any other params, optional>`

So, from the provided URL structure

```
base url = http://www.magento.com/
module front name = part
controller = view
action = index (as its the default value, when no action name is provided)
```

A modules front name is defined in the `config.xml` file of the module, as follows:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <namespace_custom_module_name>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Namespace_Custommodule</module>
                <frontName>custom_frontname</frontName>
            </args>
        </namespace_custom_module_name>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Replace `custom_frontname` inside `frontName` tag with `part`, and this should set you router correctly.

As per the first example, `http://www.magento.com/part/`, you have to create a IndexController.php with a function `indexAction()`.

For the second example, `http://www.magento.com/part/view/`, you have to create a controller named PartController.php, with method name as `indexAction()`.

Each action you create, inside a controller represents a page, so use it wisely. As a best practice, actions that works with similar data are always grouped inside a single controller.

For e.g., in CRUD applications, various operations like listing, add, edit, delete, save all actions are usually added to a single controller.